# Subset Dataframe based on the Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I'm a Python newbie so apologies if I'm asking a silly question, but I can't figure out how to subset my dataframe based on **the latest** starting CASE ID so that **all rows** are kept.

| ID | CASE ID | CHANGE_TMS | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | Case 1 | 15:12:10 | Start |
| 00000001 | Case 1 | 15:14:45 | END |
| 00000001 | Case 2 | 17:29:23 | Start |
| 00000001 | Case 2 | 18:30:23 | End |

I'm looking for the following result:

| ID | CASE ID | CHANGE_TMS | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | Case 2 | 17:29:23 | Start |
| 00000001 | Case 2 | 18:30:23 | End |

this is what I've managed to do so far but I'm not sure I'm using the index correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = r'C:\path'

# Read the csv file and extract the specified columns
columns_to_keep=['CUSTOMER_ID', 'CASE_ID', 'CHANGE_TMS','STATUS']
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=columns_to_keep)

**#change column to datetime type**
df['CHANGE_TMS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CHANGE_TMS'])

**#sent the index**
df.set_index('CASE_ID', inplace=True)

**#sort the timestamp column**
df.sort_values(by=['CUSTOMER_ID', 'CHANGE_TMS'], inplace=True)
last_case_indices = df.groupby('CASE_ID')['CHANGE_TMS'].first()

print(last_case_indices)
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? This code doesn't seem to do anything like what you're talking about and never actually uses the index, so maybe you'd be better served by learning some more first. This section of the User Guide should be a good place to start: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: And please try to provide a [mre]. It looks like the setup is all fine up to the `set_index`, so you can just provide `df` at that point, which it looks like you've essentially done, though the column names don't match. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: df[df['CASE_ID']=='Case 2']